# `Nothing` not matching a record field of type `Maybe a`

Tags: elm

I have a record type that describes an `OrderItem`:

```
type alias Product {- = some record type -}
type alias Quantity = Int

type alias OrderItem = {
      product: Product
    , quantity: Quantity
    , fillable: Maybe Bool
}
```

a function that performs a product lookup:

```
productByCode : String -> Maybe Product
```

and a function that builds an orderItem:

```
orderItem : String -> Quantity -> Result OrderItem
orderItem productCode quantity =
  let
    product = productByCode productCode
  in
    case product of
      Just p -> Ok { product = p, quantity = quantity, fillable = Nothing }
      Nothing -> Err ("Unknown product code: " ++ productCode)
```

But this function causes a compile error:

```
-- TYPE MISMATCH ---------------------------------------------- src/elm/Main.elm

The type annotation for `orderItem` does not match its definition.

65│ orderItem : String -> Quantity -> Result OrderItem
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
The type annotation is saying:

    String -> Quantity -> Result OrderItem

But I am inferring that the definition has this type:

    String
    -> Quantity
    -> Result
           String
           { fillable : Maybe a, product : Product, quantity : Quantity }
```

The error tells me the compiler isn't matching the OrderItem type because `Nothing` isn't matching `Maybe Bool` - but surely `Nothing` is a valid value here? The documentation seems to allow using it in this way.

Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type annotation should be:

```
orderItem : String -> Quantity -> Result String OrderItem
```

This tells the compiler that the value will either be of type `Ok OrderItem` or `Err String`